# If two matrices have the same 4 fundamental subspaces, then free variable submatrices must be equal. [GStrang P194 3.6.42]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

[image]

$\Large{{1.}}$ Would someone please divulge and expound the intermediate steps? 
Here's my attempt. Suppose both matrices have rank $r$, WLOG. Then $I$ has size $r \times r$, $F$ and $G$ sizes $r \times (n - r)$.
Afterwards, I define $F(i, j)$ as the $(i, j)$th entry in $F$, $g(i, j)$ as the $(i, j)$th entry in $G$.

Since $C(A^T) = C(B^T)$, thus 
$x_1 {\Large{(}} \,1, \ldots, 0, F(1, r), \ldots, F(1, n) \, {\Large{)}} + \ldots + x_r {\Large{(}} \,0, \ldots, 1, F(r, r), \ldots, F(r, n) \, {\Large{)}}  $
$ = x_1 {\Large{(}} \,1, \ldots, 0, G(1, r), \ldots, G(1, n) \, {\Large{)}} + \ldots + x_r {\Large{(}} \,0, \ldots, 1, G(r, r), \ldots, G(r, n) \, {\Large{)}}  $.

$\Large{{2.}}$ How would one divine/previse: the "key is equal row spaces" (and not the other 3 subspaces)?

Answer (score 1):

Of the four fundamental subspaces, only two are really independent. What I mean is that knowing the rowspace means that you also know the nullspace, since it is the orthogonal complement. Likewise, knowing the columnspace means you also know the left-nullspace. So whatever results you can prove by knowing that all four are equal, you can also prove by knowing that the rowspace and columnspaces are equal.

Now your matrices are given in reduced row echelon form. That should immediately scream rowspace to you. The row echelon form, by construction, is intimately related to the rowspace and the nullspace. This should prompt you to start looking at the rowspace.

Another clue that you should look at the rowspace and not the columnspace is the fact that you can read the columnspace off the two matrices right away. The form of the two matrices given means that the columnspace is entirely spanned by the first few columns corresponding to $I$. This means that the columnspace is completely independent of $F$ and $G$ in the two matrices.

As for question one, the answer is basically saying that each row of one matrix is a linear combination of the rows of the other. This is a consequence of having the same rowspace.

Why the rows must be actually equal can be seen through the following. Suppose that $I$ is $r\times r$. Look at the first row vector of $A$, which we denote $\mathbf{a}_1$. We know that $\mathbf{a}_1$ must be a linear combination of the row vectors of $B$:
$$\mathbf{a}_1 = \sum_{i=1}^r c_i\mathbf{b}_i$$
But we already know the first $r$ entries of $\mathbf{a}_1$ and each $\mathbf{b}_i$. So we can write this as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \square \end{pmatrix} = c_1\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \square \end{pmatrix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \square\end{pmatrix} + \cdots + c_r\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \square\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ \vdots \\ c_r \\ \square\end{pmatrix}$$
I've written the first $r$ entries of the rows explicitly and used $\square$ to denote the remaining entries; they are unimportant to us.

Equating entries, we must have $c_1 = 1$ and $c_i = 0$ for $i\neq 1$. Therefore we actually have $\mathbf{a}_1 = \mathbf{b}_1$.

The exact same reasoning applies to the remaining rows. The support of the pivot entries of the rows uniquely determines the reduced row echelon form, and it would not be difficult to convert the above into a proof of the uniqueness of the RREF.

For completeness, let me leave off by generalizing the result slightly by stating (without proof) the following.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be an $m\times n$ matrices. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $A$ is row equivalent to $B$.
2. $A$ has the same nullspace as $B$.
3. $A$ has the same rowspace as $B$.
4. $A$ has the same reduced row echelon form as $B$.